# Problem with eliminating rows that contain NaN in selected rows in ASCII data file

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have an ASCII data file containing NaNs in each row. My goal is to keep the rows where Column name 'Lat' is not Nan.

Here's the partial listing of my data file:
Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
fn = 'WTEC_20190304_171956_EDT_100_layer.asc'

# Read in RAOB, skip 1st 7 lines, grab the header data
df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep ='\t', skiprows=7, header=0)
df = df.astype('float64')

df2 = df.dropna(subset=['Lat'])
```

### Here's the error message after I run the last line:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\5/ipykernel_11592/339598325.py in <module>
      6 df = df.astype('float64')
      7 
----> 8 df2 = df.dropna(subset=['Lat'])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in dropna(self, axis, how, thresh, subset, inplace)
   5951             check = indices == -1
   5952             if check.any():
-> 5953                 raise KeyError(list(np.compress(check, subset)))
   5954             agg_obj = self.take(indices, axis=agg_axis)
   5955 

KeyError: ['Lat']
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Will you please paste the first 5 lines of your CSV file into the question?

Comment: skiprows=7 is moving your header=0 to the 8th position, so you're not actually picking up the column names in the first row. Or something like that...depending on where your header row is you may need to clean up the data after reading into a dataframe

Comment: In response to your request, here are the 1st 10 rows of my CSV file:

Answer (score 0):

see my comment as well, but here's an example

```
data='''    col1  col2  col3
0      1     2     3
1      1     2     3
2      1     2     3
3      1     2     3
4      1     2     3
5      1     2     3
6      1     2     3
7      1     2     3
8      1     2     3
9      1     2     3
10     1     2     3
11     1     2     3
12     1     2     3
13     1     2     3
'''
import io
# without skiprows
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' \s+', engine='python', header=0)

    col1  col2  col3
0      1     2     3
1      1     2     3
2      1     2     3
3      1     2     3
4      1     2     3
5      1     2     3
6      1     2     3
7      1     2     3
8      1     2     3
9      1     2     3
10     1     2     3
11     1     2     3
12     1     2     3
13     1     2     3

# with skip rows
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' \s+', engine='python', header=0, skiprows=7)

    6  1  2  3
0   7  1  2  3
1   8  1  2  3
2   9  1  2  3
3  10  1  2  3
4  11  1  2  3
5  12  1  2  3
6  13  1  2  3
```